# Needing help on auto scroll down on video end using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, scroll

I'm trying to get a script that when my video ends the site would scrolldown to `<main>` but I can't put it to work. A little help would be appreciated.
I made the `<script>` but it is completely not working, and I can't understand why.
The main on the code is just an example of course. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
<body>

<header>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
var video = $("#myVideo");
function videoScripting(){
    setTimeout(function () {
        var scrollToBtm = function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $('main').position().top // replace with whatever you want
        }, 4000);
        };
    }, 3000);
}
video[0].onended = function() {
  scrollToBtm(); // call function on video.onended if you want
};
}
</script>
<header>

<video controls autoplay width="100%" height="100%" id="myVideo">
        <source src="imagens/DisneyIntroFullHD1080p.mp4" type="video/mp4">

 </video>
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Awards</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img class="w-25 h-25" src="imagens/Walt-Disney-logo.png"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Characters</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Personality</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<main>
    <section class="container-fluid secao1">
        <article class="row align-self-center">
            <div class="col-3"></div>
            <img class="borda col-3 img-fluid" src="imagens/Walt_Disney_2.jpg">
            <div class="borda2 col-3 align-self-center">The most iconic animation persona in the world
                The men behind that little mouse that’s still part of children’s lifes nowadays
                The men behind the Disney empire.
                The men with a dream and the will to make it real.</div>
            <div class="col-3"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var video = $("#myVideo");
 
 var scrollToBtm = function() {
   $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('main').position().top // replace with whatever you want
   }, 4000);
};

video[0].onended = function() {
  scrollToBtm(); // call function on video.onended if you want
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

<video controls autoplay width="100%" height="100%" id="myVideo">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   
</header>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar10">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar10">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="//codeply.com">Awards</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><img class="w-25 h-25" src="imagens/Walt-Disney-logo.png"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Characters</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Personality</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<main>
    <section class="container-fluid secao1">
        <article class="row align-self-center">
            <div class="col-3"></div>
            <img class="borda col-3 img-fluid" src="imagens/Walt_Disney_2.jpg">
            <div class="borda2 col-3 align-self-center">The most iconic animation persona in the world
                The men behind that little mouse that’s still part of children’s lifes nowadays
                The men behind the Disney empire.
                The men with a dream and the will to make it real.</div>
            <div class="col-3"></div>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: It does the scrolling but on the end of the video and it scrolls too much, it goes literally to the end instead of to the <main> selector

Comment: updated my answer. I replaced with `$('main').position().top` which is main's y position.

Comment: It is almost good I added the video.onended but it didn't wait for the video to end so what am I missing?

Comment: i found it. the error was on video.onended. It should be video[0].onended because it is JQuery.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I place the video[0].onended where you said it doesn't start the video automatically and on the end it does not scroll

Comment: Ihave done some editing, now I'm trying for the script wait 30 seconds since it is the time of the video and then start, It'll display the video and scroll I edited the code. It is still not working :/ .

Comment: from what I see above, the code is wrong because you call scrollToBtm which is a local variable of your videoScripting function. (different scope). If you define the scrollToBtm function after your first line it should work.